# How to trigger two events together : onblur and onclick

Tags: javascript, html, events, web, triggers

I have an html code as below

```
    <input type="text" onblur="abc()">
    <button onclick="xyz()">
```

When the focus is on the input tag and I click on the button tag at the same time, two events must be triggered -

1. onblur : abc() - because the input has lost focus.
2. onclick : xyz() - because the button tag has got the click.

But instead only the abc() method is triggered. And when I click again on the button, the xyz() is triggered since the focus in now on the button tag.

Can anyone suggest me a method to trigger both the events together.

Comment: It does work as expected [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3s32eagv/) voting to close.

Comment: Is this a browser issue?

Comment: can u use jquery to click both element?

Comment: the issue was with the other statements and events triggered inside this method, no problem with the code. thanks all for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jquery to click both element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input,button').click(function(){
    $('input,button').click();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give id to the element and call appropriately.

```
<input type="text" id="blurText">

<button id="submitBtn">



$(document).ready(function(){

       $("#blurText").blur(function(){

               abc();

       });

       $("#submitBtn").click(function(){       

               xyz();

       });
});
```